# How to inspect value both in Mozilla Firebug?

Tags: css

When I inspect an element in Mozilla Firefox (version 47.0.1), I need to add some css rules in Firebug. I wanted to add `clear: both;`, but the options are only:

```
clear: inherit
       initial
       left
       none
       right
       unset
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/CSS/clear says:

```
Values:  

clear: none;
clear: left;
clear: right;
clear: both;
clear: inline-start;
clear: inline-end;

clear: inherit;
```

How do I add the `clear: both;` css rule to an element using Firebug?

Comment: You should just be able to type in "both", you don't have to pick from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it works fine for me:

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/1poxy505/1

In the fiddle you can inspect element on the black div tag and see clear: both; in there.

If your trying to add clear: both; in firebug, you can just do that by typing it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@DBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650337/dbs) mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395022/how-to-inspect-value-both-in-mozilla-firebug/39396316#comment66116207_39395022), you can just type in `both` in the field.

The options are only suggestions, you are free to type in anything you want.